# Nextjs 13, re-mounting issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

```
import { useRouter, useSearchParams, usePathname } from 'next/navigation';

export function useQueryParams() {
    const pathname = usePathname();
    const router = useRouter();
    const searchParams = useSearchParams()!;    
    const updateQueryParams = ({ query }: { query?: Record<string, string> }) => {
        const newSearchParams = new URLSearchParams(searchParams);
        Object.entries(query ?? {}).forEach(([key, value]) => {
            value !== '' ? newSearchParams.set(key, value) : newSearchParams.delete(key)
        });
        if(pathname) {
            const updatedUrl = `${pathname}?${decodeURIComponent(newSearchParams.toString())}`;
            router.replace(updatedUrl);
        }
    }  
    return { update: updateQueryParams };
}
```

While using useQueryParams hook's update function, due to router.replace() whole app is re-mounting, any solution to prevent re-mounting.

Answer (score 0):

You're right, try this:

```
    // query-context.js

    import { createContext, useContext, useState } from 'react';
    
    const QueryContext = createContext();
    
    export const useQueryContext = () => {
      return useContext(QueryContext);
    };
    
    export const QueryProvider = ({ children }) => {
      const [query, setQuery] = useState({});
    
      return (
        <QueryContext.Provider value={{ query, setQuery }}>
          {children}
        </QueryContext.Provider>
      );
    };
```

Wrap your application with the QueryProvider:

```
// _app.js
import { QueryProvider } from './query-context';

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <QueryProvider>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </QueryProvider>
  );
}

export default MyApp;
```

Modify your 'useQueryParams' hook to use the 'QueryContext':

```
// use-query-params.js
import { useRouter } from 'next/navigation';
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useQueryContext } from './query-context';

export function useQueryParams() {
  const router = useRouter();
  const { query, setQuery } = useQueryContext();
  const searchParams = new URLSearchParams(router.asPath.split('?')[1]);
  const pathname = router.pathname;

  useEffect(() => {
    const newQuery = {};
    searchParams.forEach((value, key) => {
      newQuery[key] = value;
    });
    setQuery(newQuery);
  }, [router.asPath]);

  const updateQueryParams = (newQuery) => {
    setQuery(newQuery);
    const updatedUrl = `${pathname}?${decodeURIComponent(new URLSearchParams(newQuery).toString())}`;
    router.replace(updatedUrl);
  };

  return { query, update: updateQueryParams };
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: In next 13, useRouter of next/router is deprecated and now we have to use useRouter of next/navigation in which shallow is not allowed.

Comment: See updated answer. By managing the query parameters using one of these solutions, you can avoid triggering a route change and prevent unnecessary re-mounting of components.